# Woocommerce subcategories dissappear when changing page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

When the URL of the products page is /?product_cat=tricka&paged=1 the subcategories are shown. When i change the page to /?product_cat=tricka&paged=2 the subcategories disappier.

I'm getting the subcategories like that:

```
<?php 
$subcategories = woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();
if ( $subcategories ) {
    echo '<div class="products subcategories row custom-category-align-and-border">', $subcategories, '</div>';
}
```

What could be the issue here?

Couldn't find solution anywhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the variable returns empty and generate the required HTML code yourself.

```php
<?php 
$subcategories = woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories();
if ( $subcategories ) {
    echo '<div class="products subcategories row custom-category-align-and-border">', $subcategories, '</div>';
}
else{
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $category_id = $category->term_id;
    custom_show_subcategories_with_images_atakanau($category_id);
}
function custom_show_subcategories_with_images_atakanau($parent_category_id) {
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'parent' => $parent_category_id
    );
    $subcategories = get_terms($args);
    
    if ($subcategories) {
        $output = '<ul class="subcategories">';

        foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
            $category_image = get_term_meta($subcategory->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            if (empty($category_image)) {
                $image_url = wc_placeholder_img_src();
            }
            else{
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($category_image);
            }

            $output .= '<li>';
            $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($subcategory->term_id) . '">';
            $output .= '<img src="' . $image_url . '" alt="' . $subcategory->name . '" />';
            $output .= '<span>' . $subcategory->name . '</span>';
            $output .= '</a>';
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
        echo $output;
    }
}
```